# Save open tabs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, bookmarks

Is there a way to save all open tabs into a temporary (or non temporary) bookmark folder?

Sometimes I have a bunch of tabs open on one topic in one windows and the same in another windows. I'd like to quickly save all open tabs in different bookmark directories so I can shutdown the computer, come back and reopen both windows.

Anyone know of some good ways to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) and [Session Manager](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bbcnbpafconjjigibnhbfmmgdbbkcjfi) extensions for Chrome.

Comment: Both look cool, I'll have to try them both. Thanks!

Comment: I also recommend Tab Cloud, which can synchronize entire groups of tabs across all Chrome installations (and allows you to open a tab group with a single click.)

Answer (score 4):

If you right-click a tab, there is a "Bookmark All Tabs..." option you can use.

Comment: I am thinking to develop a extension which will save and share open browsers with fellow users - specific to a subject such as IIS,or Message queue instllation...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's already solved, but if you are looking for an extension that works on **multiple computers** without the need of sending files over via email or such, then take a look at [TabCloud](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/npecfdijgoblfcgagoijgmgejmcpnhof?hl=de). You can't drag and drop items into groups, but doing it by hand still beats every other extension if you rely on **syncing** your tabs.

Update: I can't recommend Pinboard.in highly enough. It has this feature among several others.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [OneTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall?hl=en), as it's a great way to maintain URLs persistently until you decide what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't 'save' the tabs at all, you can recover them the next time you open Chrome by going to the new tab page and selecting the first under "Recently Closed" (it's at the bottom)