# How can I save the current opened pages on Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save open tabs in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/173620/save-open-tabs-in-chrome)

I usually suspend/hibernate my Windows instead rebooting it letting all the current opened pages on Chrome to the next time I recover my saved session on Windows.

However, sometimes the recover process result in some error and I lost all these pages that I just left loaded. There is some way to save (in disk) all these URLs or pages that I left on "idle"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go:

Settings/Ratchet (upper right corner) >>> Preferences

Then, under the "Basics" section, under "On Startup" select "Reopen the pages that were open last".
I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Session Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bbcnbpafconjjigibnhbfmmgdbbkcjfi), an addon for Chrome

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this make the bookmark of your current page which you want to open again. And when you hibernate the windows 7 its some functions doesn't work correctly until you don't reboot it.