# Chrome - restoring opened tabs

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

I need to open specific tabs when chrome starts.
or 
I need to open all the tabs which were opened previously before quitting Chrome.

How would I do that ? Please guide me - I am a new user to chrome.

Please See : Well ! I already have gone through - [Save open tabs in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/173620) Answers of that questions, suggest to install plugins. I am asking for any kind of inbuilt facility.

Comment: Well ! I already have gone through - http://superuser.com/questions/173620. Answers of that questions, suggest to install plugins. I am asking for any kind of inbuild facility.

Comment: (A close vote? :( - No need to be rude ! I am new to Chrome :) )

Comment: Even you can use the Opera 11 it's too good and reliable than firefox.

Comment: @sugar-SagarKothari Yes I'm quite sorry! I didn't read your comment and voted to close. With the comment added, I see it is a "different" question! **So my vote close was ill-founded**. Please add relevant information about your question to your question instead of adding it as a comment. This way, potential readers will get all the information they need from the question and won't overlook crucial information. Click "Edit" at the bottom of your question to edit your question.

Comment: @BloodPhilla - edited the question ( & also answered what I wanted :) )

Comment: please don't add signatures to your post. Refer [faq#signatures]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Chrome preferences (Wrench > Preferences), there's an entry under Basics called: "On Startup". Here you can select "Reopen the pages that were open last", and it'll automatically open the same tabs you had open the last time, whenever you open the browser again.

Note, it'll only remember the tabs for the last window that was closed, so if you first close a window with 20 tabs, and then a window with just one tab, only the one tab will be restored automatically. If this happens accidentally, you'll be able to find the 20 tab session in the "Recently Closed" list on the new tab menu, however, so you can still restore them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the *Continue where you left off* option selected on the *On Startup* options menu, you can save all opened **windows and tabs** by using Chrome's "Exit" feature.

On Windows, select the Chrome menu from an open window, and choose Exit.
On Mac, select the Chrome menu from the system menu bar, and choose "Quit Google Chrome."

Note that this is a different way of exiting Chrome than most are used to -- which is to just close the last browser window open. Doing that will only re-open the tabs that were in the last closed window.